# Excel VBA - =lookup in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this formula to get info from another sheet. I would like to make it in a macro.

```
=LOOKUP(Sheet1!F2,{"FL01","FL12","FL21","FL31","FL34"},{"ORLANDO PICKLIST","TAMPA PICKLIST","JAX PICKLIST","NAPLES PICKLIST","MIAMI PICKLIST"})
```

Also the answer to be in sheet2 B2 center font size 24 .

Thank you

Comment: You can just record a macro and enter your formula then stop the macro. Then you will have your answer

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Formula = "=LOOKUP(Sheet1!F2,{" & """" & "FL01" & """" & ",FL12" & """ ",FL21" & """" & ",FL31" & """" & ",FL34" & """" & "},{" & """" & "ORLANDO PICKLIST" & """" & ",TAMPA PICKLIST" & """" & ",JAX PICKLIST" & """" & ",NAPLES PICKLIST" & """" & ",MIAMI PICKLIST" & """" & "})"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [recording](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) it

[image]

you will get something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=LOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[4],{""FL01"";""FL12"";""FL21"";""FL31"";""FL34""},{""ORLANDO PICKLIST"";""TAMPA PICKLIST"";""JAX PICKLIST"";""NAPLES PICKLIST"";""MIAMI PICKLIST""})"
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 24
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    End With
End Sub
```

Where selection is which cell I selected when I started recording ("`B2`"). From here you can play around with the code. You will get a feeling for how Excel "Translate" your formulas and your format options into code.

By edit the selection part (`Selection.`) we can be more explicit which worksheet and which range we want to apply the new code into...

```
Sub Macro3_Changes()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").FormulaArray = _
        "=LOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[4],{""FL01"";""FL12"";""FL21"";""FL31"";""FL34""},{""ORLANDO PICKLIST"";""TAMPA PICKLIST"";""JAX PICKLIST"";""NAPLES PICKLIST"";""MIAMI PICKLIST""})"
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 24
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is some interesting note, I assume that you had an Array formula. I enter your formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter. The macro records that too and translate it as  `FormulaArray`. If I have just enter the formula it would have been `FormulaR1C1` which is a relative formula from the section you selected.

Comment: The macro recorder _is_ a great way to figure out to start writing VBA code. Extra +1 for making note of the fact that it writes _terrible_ (but functional) code that then needs to be massaged into something decent.

Comment: And [here's a good SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) on how to avoid using `.Select/.Activate`.